# GroupBy with different parameters

Tags: c#, list, linq, model-view-controller, group-by

I have one query with `groupBy` parameters depends on the user input. If the condition is true, query will be grouped with `DOB` attribute. else, it doesnt need to.
Here is my code

```
   var userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age});
       if (isBaby)
       {
          userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, x.DOB });
       }
```

but i got an error which the parameters is not same. The latter code is to select from this query like this.

```
     var allList= userList.Select({ 
        ...
       }).ToList();
```

I dont want to create two `select` list because it is easier to manage if only use one `select` list.

Edited:
This is the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SystemLinq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: string name, string age>, Domains.User>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SystemLinq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: string name, string age, string DOB>, Domains.User>>'
```

enter code here

Comment: Could you please include the error message?

Comment: Regarding the error, why don't you do this: `
       if (isBaby){
          var userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, x.DOB });} else{ var userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age});}`

Comment: @fyrz You are trying to group an already grouped list
      ` if (isBaby)
       {
          userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, x.DOB });
       }
       else
       {
            user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age});
        }`

Comment: but then i cannot use the var userList outside if else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `DOB` is a `DateTime`:

```
var userList = user.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, dob = isBaby ? x.DOB : DateTime.MinValue });
```

That way the expression is always the same type, but won't cause an additional tier of grouping when `isBaby` is false.

Comment: i have tried this. but it still group the DateTime.MinValue when the isBaby is false

Comment: Yes, but it will not affect the groupings i.e. you will have the same number of groups in the result.

Comment: but i want to show it as list. if the list has 5 rows, i want to show all rows instead one.

Comment: @fyrz I'm not sure what you mean. Can you add a sample input and expected output to your question?

Comment: It is ok i will use this solution and change other code. But can i replace DateTime.MinValue with DateTime.Now? Because i cannot save the value in the database.

Comment: @fyrz The `GroupBy` is for querying, not saving. If you need to save the result in the database, I would replace `DateTime.MinValue` with `null`, rather than using an arbitrary value such as `DateTime.Now` (although `DateTime.Now` would work in the `GroupBy`).

Comment: i use the value to save in the db. if i use DateTime.Minvalue it will return error

Comment: @fyrz Can you update the question showing where you attempt to save to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Well you are constructing two different results in the group by...

Var implicitly tries to assume the type, and the first assignment is an anon type with only Name and Age. The second one adds DOB which is a different anon type.

Something like

```
new { x.Name, x.Age, DateOfBirth = isBaby ? x.DOB : DateTime.MinValue }
```

Would fix it